# Canvas/Stage Size in Flash is too small and cannot show entire level

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash

This isn't directly a programing problem but I feel it still can fall under the catagory, I am sorry if this is the wrong place. I am making a game in flash using box2d and I decided to draw the levels in flash as the level design would look better, The levels are very large ( this level is 10,000 pixels long) and the canvas in flash just won't display anything.

[image: platformer]

The preview in the library seems to be able to display the drawing longer than the one on the stage. How do I go about making the canvas longer? Should I try upgrading to a newer version of flash, does that version allow this?

Comment: What version of Flash do you have? In CS5.5 at least, the canvas area seems to expand when I stretch out an extremely large shape. Ideally, you would cut your level up as others have suggested, but you could try putting a shrunken version of your level MovieClip on stage, then double click it to "Edit in place".

Answer (score 0):

You just don't put everything at once over your canvas, instead draw only those level primitives or parts that are visible right now. Or, if your level is basically a pretty simple shape, you can just change its X and Y so that the relevant part of the level is displayed on stage.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use giant bitmaps - they use a lot of memory, and even if not all of the content is  visible, they will degrade performance considerably. For this reason, Flash imposes a size limit of 4095x4095 pixels (or an equal amount of pixels in rectangular formats).

The way to deal with this is to tile your graphics into parts of equal size, preferably smaller than the stage (1/2 or 1/3 side length is a good measure). You then place them all as a grid into a larger Sprite or MovieClip and set `visible=false;` on each tile. Then, at runtime, your game loop must check for each frame, which of the tiles should actually appear on the stage - and only those should then be set to `visible=true;`. That way, you reduce the amount of pixels drawn to what is absolutely necessary, and keep screen memory usage to a minimum.